# ".getElementsByTagName is not a function" on XML in Node

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to get specific elements from an XML file with Node.

```
console.log(file);
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="1">"
(book info)
</book>
```

And so on with the other books.

But, the code below:

```
var bookTags = file.getElementsByTagName("book");
console.log(bookTags);
```

outputs:

> `TypeError`: `file.getElementsByTagName` is not a function

Shouldn't `.getElementsByTagName` work here?

I would like to get specific XML elements to be able to delete book elements based on the id (not hard coded though). I do not want to use jQuery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: What library are you using to open the file, and what browser are you using? An XML file is not a DOM, so getElementsByTagName is not valid. file could just be a string.

Comment: what type is `file`?

Comment: I use fs.readFile. Chrome and Firefox produce the same result. OK, I thought getElementsByTagName would work on XML files.

Comment: console.log(typeof file) === string,
OK, that's a problem. Should have thought about checking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use DOM methods on something which is not a DOM. I assume your XML output is a string from reading the file, you need to use some sort of library to parse and manipulate the XML like [xml2js.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js)